# adding viewController to tab bar controller crashes

Tags: ios4, ios5

I am new to iOS, i am using Xcode 4.3.2, and i have created a project with tabView, where by default it has two view controllers. I am creating a new one now,

ThirdView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ThirdView : UIViewController

@end


#import "ThirdView.h"

@implementation ThirdView

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Third", @"Third");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Third"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}


@end
```

and in the appDelicate.m

```
viewController3 = [[ThirdView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdView" bundle:nil];
```

and added viewController3 to tabBarController.

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, viewController3 ,nil];
```

The Problem is:
When i execute the code in the device, i could see the third tab, but the moment i click, it crashes.
Where i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check the class name of the third view controller in you nib file.

Comment: Sorry, my mistaken, i was typing wrongly. Edited.